# Regular expression that does not accept string less than 3 alphabets and also restrict numbers in the start

Tags: regex, python-re

I am working on the lambda function in python. I want a regular expression that does not accept less than three alphabets. The other thing, it should not accept numbers at the start such as "9ss" or "3s".
If a digit comes after the first word it should be acceptable. For example, "my 2 laptops not working" should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match your rule: `[a-zA-Z]\w{2,}`

For the point " If a digit comes after the first word it should be acceptable", for me it's a separate condition that is best tested separately from the previous regex.

However, if you want to do it as a single regex, you can do it like this:

```
([a-zA-Z]\w{2,}|\d+(?=\s+[a-zA-Z]\w{2,}))
```

Comment: @RehanCH Your welcome. Feel free to mark the subject as answered